# Redis active defrag didn't work after I enabled it a week ago

Tags: redis

I have a 3-node redis sentinel cluster, all 3 servers always reported the memory fragment ratio was over 1.5.

I enabled active defrag a week ago, but it seemed not work at all. The Stats of active defrag were always zero, and servers still reported high fragment ratio, even something like 2.4.

Is there anything wrong?

Active defrag configuration:

```
active-defrag-cycle-min=1
active-defrag-cycle-max=50
active-defrag-threshold-lower=10
active-defrag-threshold-upper=100
active-defrag-max-scan-fields=1000
active-defrag-ignore-bytes=104857600
```

Redis info of Master server:

```
redis_version:6.2.6
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:74bade077d43617f
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:c11-builtin
gcc_version:8.4.1
process_id:199595
process_supervised:systemd
run_id:38d4f899d1eb358916795a2f338ad08e80026068
tcp_port:6379
server_time_usec:1697448182658574
uptime_in_seconds:7287845
uptime_in_days:84
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:2949366
executable:/usr/local/bin/redis-server
config_file:/usr/local/redis_sentinel/redis.conf
io_threads_active:0

# Clients
connected_clients:67
cluster_connections:0
maxclients:10000
client_recent_max_input_buffer:180
client_recent_max_output_buffer:0
blocked_clients:9
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:9

# Memory
used_memory:51383784
used_memory_human:49.00M
used_memory_rss:85032960
used_memory_rss_human:81.09M
used_memory_peak:12940712288
used_memory_peak_human:12.05G
used_memory_peak_perc:0.40%
used_memory_overhead:5350844
used_memory_startup:810432
used_memory_dataset:46032940
used_memory_dataset_perc:91.02%
allocator_allocated:51560656
allocator_active:54521856
allocator_resident:88977408
total_system_memory:8347443200
total_system_memory_human:7.77G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
allocator_frag_ratio:1.06
allocator_frag_bytes:2961200
allocator_rss_ratio:1.63
allocator_rss_bytes:34455552
rss_overhead_ratio:0.96
rss_overhead_bytes:-3944448
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.66
mem_fragmentation_bytes:33693464
mem_not_counted_for_evict:92
mem_replication_backlog:1048576
mem_clients_slaves:41024
mem_clients_normal:1354668
mem_aof_buffer:96
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
lazyfreed_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
current_cow_size:0
current_cow_size_age:0
current_fork_perc:0.00
current_save_keys_processed:0
current_save_keys_total:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:533
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1697448166
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:0
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:3489792
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:5005312
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0
aof_current_size:26769528
aof_base_size:13064746
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:21

# Stats
total_connections_received:231741246
total_commands_processed:2183599052
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:403
total_net_input_bytes:283298218758
total_net_output_bytes:4078789822776
instantaneous_input_kbps:41.79
instantaneous_output_kbps:496.23
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:18
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:6
expired_keys:51239027
expired_stale_perc:5.25
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:1548806
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:1789109473
keyspace_misses:69189786
pubsub_channels:1
pubsub_patterns:1
latest_fork_usec:26482
total_forks:30008
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_error_replies:3291
dump_payload_sanitizations:0
total_reads_processed:2410087087
total_writes_processed:4207876662
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:2
slave0:ip=192.168.30.29,port=6379,state=online,offset=170197343400,lag=0
slave1:ip=192.168.30.28,port=6379,state=online,offset=170197340500,lag=0
master_failover_state:no-failover
master_replid:9d1c5eeaf5b4ee57fc3d996dc7112505e02d80e2
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:170197373540
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:170196324965
repl_backlog_histlen:1048576

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:129151.245824
used_cpu_user:86751.143899
used_cpu_sys_children:1929.085760
used_cpu_user_children:5563.625211
used_cpu_sys_main_thread:127811.393478
used_cpu_user_main_thread:86581.165811

# Modules

# Errorstats
errorstat_BUSYGROUP:count=2041
errorstat_ERR:count=84
errorstat_LOADING:count=257
errorstat_MISCONF:count=703
errorstat_NOAUTH:count=206

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=24561,expires=24555,avg_ttl=2766005216
```

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.